# Checking out of bounds in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is this code really checking out of bounds on the array?

The limits in this case is 0 - 20 in a 2d-array

```
int noOfNeighbors(game *g, int row, int column){                                                      
    int aliveCounter = 0;

    for(int rows=-1; rows<=1; rows++) {
        for(int cols=-1; cols<=1; cols++) {

            if((rows || cols)) {
                if(row+rows < (*g).rows && row+rows >= 0){
                    if(column+cols < (*g).columns && column+cols >= 0){
                        if(isAlive(g,row+rows,column+cols)){
                            aliveCounter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } //end cols
    }//end rows
    return aliveCounter;
}//end noOfNeighbors
```

Where

```
    typedef struct {
    char current;
    char next;
} cell;


 typedef struct {
    cell field[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
    int rows;
    int columns;
    char aliveChar;
    char deadChar;
} game;
```

and rows and columns are set to 20

Updated code and now it checks 0-19

Comment: We need the declaration of the `game` type

Comment: Looks like `(*g).rows` and `(*g).columns` (somebody afraid of the `->` operator?) will be your upper limits (20).

Comment: Still no array access in this code...

Comment: Just be aware that `char a[20]; a[20];` is invalid. `a[19]` is the last element in that array, it's a reference to the twentieth element (index start at 0).

Comment: What have you against the use of `->`? `(*g).rows` instead of `g->rows` is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this code really checking out of bounds on the array?

**Yes**. Can you tell us what you don't understand so we can be more specific?

Also, you could change:

```
(*g).rows
```

to

```
g->rows
```

It's more easy to read.

**Edit:** I've just noticed that the code in the question has been edited and fixed. So I guess you found the problem yourself: in the initial question, there was a problem in the comparison (`<=` instead of `<`).

Comment: Is there a difference between (*g).rows and g->rows except it makes it easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

***This is not an answer, but too long for a comment:***

***The code you are presenting*** has many issues: I will only address these:

As others have already noted in comments and in another answer:  use g->rows instead of (*g).rows

***In the code section***:

```
int noOfNeighbors(game *g, int row, int column){                                                      
    int aliveCounter = 0;

    for(int rows=-1; rows<=1; rows++) {
        for(int cols=-1; cols<=1; cols++) {

            if((rows || cols)) {   
               if(row+rows < (*g).rows && row+rows >= 0){
```

The way it is written, the results of the last line are indeterminate.  That is, the inner loop, the first to reach 1 is cols (rows is still -1) and in the comparison `(*g).rows && row+rows >= 0)`  `(*g).rows has not yet been initialized.

Then, in the line following:

```
                   if(column+cols < (*g).columns && column+cols >= 0){
```

For the same reason will have indeterminate results.

Based on what is presented, there is no way to know for sure when execution flow will finally get to the core of the loop:

```
                     if(isAlive(g,row+rows,column+cols)){
                         aliveCounter++;
                     }
```

Suggest first that you provide a code segment that complies with ***[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)***, and maybe an explanation of what the exact intent is, and where it is falling short of expectations.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be indeterminate results. (also, rows equals -1 in the first loop, not 0).

Comment: `(*g).rows` is probably initialized somewhere else, before the call to this function.

Comment: @Maxime agreed on both, will fix my -1 error.  regarding _why indeterminate?_, I do not see code where it has been initialized, or where OP has stated so.  It is a factor, one of many why this question is difficult to answer.  My answer by the way states up front "it is not an answer", just a wordy comment

Comment: It's kinda obvious that `g->rows` is the number of lines of the array and `g->columns` the number of columns of the array. And the question is about checking the boundaries. Now, if there is a bug in the isAlive function or if `g` is not properly initialized, there's nothing we can do for the OP :).

Comment: @Maxime - Again, agreed.  My comment, (in pseudo answer form) is simply trying to point out some deficiencies with respect to SSCCE.  I do not always site this (_SSCCE_), and certainly would never make an issue of it, _unless_ getting to the requested answer requires bumping into deficiencies of this type.